# How to replace feed_dict when using an input pipeline?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Suppose you have an network that has worked with `feed_dict` so far to inject data into a graph. Every few epochs, I evaluated the training and test loss by feeding a batch from either dataset to my graph.

Now, for performance reasons, I decided to use an input pipeline. Take a look at this dummy example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

dataset_size = 200
batch_size= 5
dimension = 4

# create some training dataset
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.\
    from_tensor_slices(np.random.normal(2.0,size=(dataset_size,dimension)).
    astype(np.float32))

dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size) # take batches

iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
x = tf.cast(iterator.get_next(),tf.float32)
w = tf.Variable(np.random.normal(size=(1,dimension)).astype(np.float32))

loss_func = lambda x,w: tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(x-w)) # notice that the loss function is a mean!
loss = loss_func(x,w) # this is the loss that will be minimized
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # train one epoch
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    for i in range(dataset_size//batch_size):
        # the training step will update the weights based on ONE batch of examples each step
        loss1,_ = sess.run([loss,train_op])
        print('train step {:d}.  batch loss {:f}.'.format(i,loss1))

        # I want to print the loss from another dataset (test set) here
```

**Printing the loss of the training data is no problem, but how do I do this for another dataset?** When using `feed_dict`, I simply got a batch from said set and fed it a value for x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things you can do for that. One simple option could be something like having two datasets and iterators and use [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) to switch between them. However, the more powerful way of doing it is to use an iterator that supports this directly. See the guide on [how to create iterators](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#creating_an_iterator) for a description of the various iterator types. For example, using a reinitializable iterator you could have something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

dataset_size = 200
dataset_test_size = 20
batch_size= 5
dimension = 4

# create some training dataset
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.\
    from_tensor_slices(np.random.normal(2.0,size=(dataset_size,dimension)).
    astype(np.float32))

dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size) # take batches

# create some test dataset
dataset_test = tf.data.Dataset.\
    from_tensor_slices(np.random.normal(2.0,size=(dataset_test_size,dimension)).
    astype(np.float32))

dataset_test = dataset_test.batch(batch_size) # take batches

iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(dataset.output_types,
                                           dataset.output_shapes)

dataset_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(dataset)
dataset_test_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(dataset_test)

x = tf.cast(iterator.get_next(),tf.float32)
w = tf.Variable(np.random.normal(size=(1,dimension)).astype(np.float32))

loss_func = lambda x,w: tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(x-w)) # notice that the loss function is a mean!
loss = loss_func(x,w) # this is the loss that will be minimized
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # train one epoch
    sess.run(dataset_init_op)
    for i in range(dataset_size//batch_size):
        # the training step will update the weights based on ONE batch of examples each step
        loss1,_ = sess.run([loss,train_op])
        print('train step {:d}.  batch loss {:f}.'.format(i,loss1))

    # print test loss
    sess.run(dataset_test_init_op)
    for i in range(dataset_test_size//batch_size):
        loss1 = sess.run(loss)
        print('test step {:d}.  batch loss {:f}.'.format(i,loss1))
```

You can do something similar with a feedable iterator, depending on what you find more convenient, and I suppose even with an initializable iterator, for example making a boolean dataset that then you map to some data with [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond), although that would not be a very natural way to do it.

---

EDIT:

Here is how you can do it with an initializable iterator, actually in a cleaner way than what I was initially thinking, so maybe you actually like this more:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

dataset_size = 200
dataset_test_size = 20
batch_size= 5
dimension = 4

# create data
data = tf.constant(np.random.normal(2.0,size=(dataset_size,dimension)), tf.float32)
data_test = tf.constant(np.random.normal(2.0,size=(dataset_test_size,dimension)), tf.float32)
# choose data
testing = tf.placeholder_with_default(False, ())
current_data = tf.cond(testing, lambda: data_test, lambda: data)
# create dataset
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(current_data)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
# create iterator
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

x = tf.cast(iterator.get_next(),tf.float32)
w = tf.Variable(np.random.normal(size=(1,dimension)).astype(np.float32))

loss_func = lambda x,w: tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(x-w)) # notice that the loss function is a mean!
loss = loss_func(x,w) # this is the loss that will be minimized
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # train one epoch
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    for i in range(dataset_size//batch_size):
        # the training step will update the weights based on ONE batch of examples each step
        loss1,_ = sess.run([loss,train_op])
        print('train step {:d}.  batch loss {:f}.'.format(i,loss1))

    # print test loss
    sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={testing: True})
    for i in range(dataset_test_size//batch_size):
        loss1 = sess.run(loss)
        print('test step {:d}.  batch loss {:f}.'.format(i,loss1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So that means at definition the iterator is no longer bound to a specific dataset until I define the initializer, right? And could you elaborate more on what you mean with your last statement? (I didn't get the idea with the boolean dataset)

Comment: @DocDriven Yes, that's right, the dataset that the iterator iterates is undetermined until you create and run an initialization operation. I have added another version using an initializable iterator, actually it can also be used cleanly here.

Comment: I tested it and it worked flawlessly. I prefer your first version though, as it is more explicit.